# Difference in the datapath of Load Upper Immediate to Load Word in a 32 bit MIPS processor

Tags: vhdl, mips

For the MIPS insturction `Load Word` I have got the following Datapath:

[image]

How does the datapath for the Instruction `Load Upper Immediate` looks like?

Comment: Pretty much the same, but with no reading from Memory(data)? The value for LUI is encoded as the lower 16-bits of the 32-bit opcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had these pictures sitting around except for the red lines.

The two instructions differ in semantics:

[image: LUI and LW instructions]

$t is the destination register, $i is an immediate value.

LUI:

[image: LUI data path]

LW:

[image: LW data path]

The images are all links to their full size versions.

In a real implementation the muxes to the ALU could likely produce 0 and 1 constants.

And along the bottom of those pipeline diagrams the `$t` should actually be `t`, the pointer to the target or destination register.